# What to do when a user has simply copied other users' answers on the same question?

Tags: discussion

A user has posted two answers but the problem is that [s]he has just copy pasted the answers given before in the thread. Here are the 2 answers I came across.

https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/386860/224025

https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/386862/224025

Although I am new here, I don't think copy-pasting other answers "as is" is allowed in the community. What flag should I use to indicate that the answer is just a plain copy-paste of another answer to the same question?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Ideally, use a custom flag and tell us the answer is copied. Custom is better because copied answers are often good answers and the flag interface will only show us the flagged post. So it might look like a perfectly decent answer unless you tell us it's been copied and we open the relevant page to see the plagiarism.

Answer (score 5):

stackexchange is the best community that checks and prevents plagiarism. Flag the content that you found as a copy and the moderators will look into it. The meta stackexchange clearly answered this question. You can find it [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/160071/what-to-do-when-plagiarism-is-discovered).

I was also found for the same guilt previous month and let me share the content mail I received after suspending my account for seven days:

> "It has come to our attention that several of your answers consisted
>   primarily or entirely of text copied from other answers or websites.
>   We prefer not to simply copy content already available elsewhere in
>   lieu of creating something that adds value to this site specifically.
>
> Whenever possible, we prefer that posts be your own original work, but
>   when a great answer already exists elsewhere, including a small
>   passage of text from another source can be a great way to support your
>   solution. But please note that we require full attribution with a link
>   to the original author, and please be sure you are not copying content
>   without permission.
>
> Thank you, and I look forward to your contributions in the future.
>
> We have temporarily suspended your account; you may return after 7
>   days."

So you can be happy that your contents have got enough respect and value in stack.